# How to fill a strings dataframe depend on dataframe or list?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a huge dataframe with names and I want to fill it with the number of another dataframe or list. How can I implement it? Thanks in advance.

```
#For example
#I want to fill df1 with the number in df2
df1=data.frame(c("J","A","A"),c("A","K","K"))
l=table(c("J","A","K","A","A","J","A"))
df2 =as.data.frame(l)
 > df1
  c..J....A....A.. c..A....k....k..
1                J                A
2                A                K
3                A                K
> df2                   
   Var1 Freq
1    A    4
2    J    2
3    K    1
#ideal results
 c..J....A....A.. c..A....K....K..
1             2                 4
2             4                 1
3             4                 1
```

Comment: In the dplyr package you can use left_join: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a combination of `lapply` and `match`:

```
output <- as.data.frame(lapply(df1, function(x) df2$Freq[match(x, df2$Var1)]))
```

If you want to write over `df1`, you can do

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) df2$Freq[match(x, df2$Var1)])
```

instead of the call to `as.data.frame`

Comment: Perfect! your answer is perfect. Thank you

Comment: Thank you~ Will take your answer but it still needs 8 min wait xD

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using `hashmap`. This creates a hash lookup table/dictionary from `df2` then lookup each "key" in `df1` and replaces it with the corresponding value:

```
library(hashmap)

lookup <- hashmap(as.character(df2$Var1), df2$Freq)
df3 <- as.data.frame(lapply(df1, function(x) lookup[[x]]))
```

**Result:**

```
> lookup
## (character) => (integer)
##         [J] => [2]      
##         [K] => [1]      
##         [A] => [4] 

> df3
  c..J....A....A.. c..A....K....K..
1                2                4
2                4                1
3                4                1
```